# What is the winning position in Monopoly Empire?

Tags: monopoly-empire

In Monopoly Empire what is the official winning position for a player?

The rules seem ambiguous by stating that the winner is the first person to build the tower to the top, but that raises two questions:

1) Can the tower 'spill over' the top?  For instance, if you need to fill one space can a 4-space billboard be bought to win the game?

and

2) Do the billboards have to fit in the tower spaces perfectly?

Answer (score 4):

First off I don't see much of a difference between your 2 questions.

The rules state:

> If you’re the first to hit the top, you win!

This means you have to fill the entire tower with billboards, including "*spilling over*". No, you do not have to fit the billboards in the tower exactly. Anything beyond the top point doesn't matter anymore since you've already won.

Answer (score 0):

Once a person has reached the top of the billboard they have won, no cards such as ‘you're fired’ or any other cards to counter act that persons win as they have already won.

Comment: Hey Dan, welcome to B&CG ... mind including a link or some quote of the rules to give your answer some backup?

Answer (score -2):

If the person has filled their tower, the other people play their turn before the opponent can win the game.

Comment: Could you add some citation from the rules to back that up?